# Is the database created in MySQL with terminal different from the database that show in the PhpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have created a database in MySQL with terminal, and I tried to find it in PhpMyAdmin I couldn't find it. My question is, are those two databases different from each other or did I do something wrong that is why it didn't show up?

Answer (score 2):

PHPMyAdmin is just a web GUI that acts as a *client* for interacting with the MySQL *Server*. In the terminal, you access the *server* using the `mysql` command-line *client*, and create a database on the *server*.

Now, both of these clients can be configured to use any MySQL server that they can access over the network. The command-line client defaults to connecting to `127.0.0.1` on port `3306` (or */var/run/mysql.sock* but that's unimportant in this case). In PHPMyAdmin,`config.php` defines what server you connect to. I don't remember the defaults, but servers are configured via `$cfg['Servers']`. [This document](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html) explains the configuration. So, you should be able to look at `config.php` and determine whether or not you're connecting to `127.0.0.1` port 3306.

Another possible reason you might not see the DB in PHPMyAdmin is if `only_db` is set in `config.php`. Look for `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['only_db']`.

Also ensure that you actually created the database and that it shows in `SHOW DATABASES;` in the `mysql` command-line client.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @mayleficent Your phpMyAdmin comes as a package with php, mysql and extra apps. So if you have installed any mysql server explicitly that would be totally differant from mysql in xamp/wamp package. So if you remove that explicitly installed mysql you can access the mysql linked with phpmyadmin. To goto terminal associated with phpmyadmin, then you have to browse to the folder in your xamp/wamp. the path appears as shown below.

```
       C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql -u root -p admin
```